# can i push the index in recursive function?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, indexing, push

**my recursive array,that i should find last element and the index**

```js
let array = [1, [2, "kkkk", [9, "some", ["six", "seven", 6666, [8, "10", [10,["you find me"]]]]]]];

function findIndex(arr) {
    for (let [index, element] of arr.entries()){
        let array = [];
        if(typeof element === "object"){
            findIndex(element);
            array.push(index);
            console.log(array);
        }
    }
}    
findIndex(array)
```

1. i add this line
    `let array = []`
2. in console i should have only index like this [1,2,2,3,2], but now i have indexes in different arrays [1][2].....
3. it must be recursive function.
4. can i do it with this example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let array = [1, [2, "kkkk", [9, "some", ["six", "seven", 6666, [8, "10", [10, ["you find me"]]]]]]];

const getIndexArray = (array) => {

  const recursiveFnc = (array, acc = []) => {

    // Get index of the last element in a current array
    const lastIndex = array.length - 1;
    // Get the last element in a current array
    const lastElement = array[lastIndex];

    // Push index of last element
    acc.push(lastIndex);

    // If last element is an array go in that array recursively, if not return the last element
    return Array.isArray(lastElement) ? recursiveFnc(lastElement, acc) : acc;
  };

  return recursiveFnc(array);

};

const result = getIndexArray(array);
```